# Undelete my post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java/

Tags: support

My post in [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java/) question has been deleted. These are the details.

deleted by Martijn Pieters♦ 27 mins ago

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question. – Martijn Pieters♦ 26 mins ago

After receiving comments from moderator

1) I have deleted my answers in two other questions

2) I have marked both of those questions as duplicate of question quoted in above questions.

[Split strings keeping all trailing empty elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040614/how-would-you-split-these-lines-of-strings/)

and

[Java string.split - by multiple character delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492672/java-string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter)

Since I would like to post my answer in [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java/), please undelete my answer as I have implemented the suggestions of  Martijn Pieters.

Comment: The question isn't a duplicate; one asks how to split a string; and the other asks how to split a string by multiple delimiters.

Comment: The answers in how-to-split-a-string-in-java/ will address all queries in both questions

Comment: @GeorgeStocker:  I'm not convinced that there isn't a dupe here.  The answer is fundamentally the same:  use `String#split`.  There are no multiple delimiters to be had in either question.

Comment: Aside: when writing ordinary paragraph text on Stack Overflow, the whole thing does not need bold and italics. These are chiefly for highlighting or emphasing a few words, not whole sentences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you deleted the older copy, I've undeleted the newer answer.

In future, please just flag the answer for moderator attention; that way it'll reach the moderators far more directly than a post on Meta does. There is nothing for the community to discuss on an individual case like this.

Comment: Sure. Will do the same in future. I am understanding more about working style of site. I am 4-5 months old in this site.

Answer (score 2):

So...there are two things to note here.  One of these is entirely procedural and the other is more anecdotal.  I'll denote these clearly.

**Procedural**:  The likely action that was taken by the moderator was to remove the exactly duplicated answer from both questions.  To my understanding, this is something that they can identify and take action on accordingly.  The chief advice is, if two questions can be answered satisfactorily by the *same* answer, then the likely scenario is that one question is a duplicate of another.  Instead of posting the same answer in two different questions, **vote to close as a duplicate.**

**Anecdotal**:  Looking at your answer, it doesn't really add info that's not already covered elsewhere.  It also does it in a more complex way; you're building out an entire regex when you just need to split around one token.  I wouldn't have elected to *delete* the question, but it'd be something I'd downvote, since no new knowledge has been added.

Comment: The difference between my two answers: One does not talk about JDK bug and other in deleted post talk about jdk bug. This info would be useful for developers using the problematic version

Comment: @ravindra:  Not unless the user was explicitly encountering the JDK bug.  Without that context, that sort of information adds more noise than signal.

Comment: This question is 6 years old and things have been changed. The bug was introduced in some version and was fixed in other version. I can say that issue exists between x and y versions and bug is not reproducible with y version or later.

Comment: @ravindra And that information would belong in a question about that bug.  It doesn't belong in every single question that ever uses that operation.